# Regex pattern to read an Web.config

Tags: regex, salt-stack

I need your valuable help, in reading a connection string value using regex - 
Idea is to read the pattern using saltstack state file, and replace with VSTS variable.

Could you please help , how can I read the  value ?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301880
  -->
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-WebApplication45-20140804053515.mdf;Initial Catalog=aspnet-WebApplication45-20140804053515;Integrated Security=True"
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <system.web>
    <authentication mode="None" />
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.1" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.1" />
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules>
      <remove name="FormsAuthenticationModule" />
    </modules>
  </system.webServer>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-5.1.0.0" newVersion="5.1.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Optimization" 
  </entityFramework>
</configuration>
```

Below is my salt state file :

[image]

Thanks,

Comment: XML and regex are not good friends. Use a parser, it is simpler, faster and much more maintainable.

Answer (score 0):

I use a Powershell script to replace the values of the connection string in the web.config.

After I "catch" the connection string I run this code:

```
$dbServer = [regex]::Match($connection, '(?i)data source=([^;]+)').Groups[1].Value
$newConnection = $connection.Replace($dbServer+';', $newSqlServerName+';')
$dbName = [regex]::Match($connection, '(?i)initial catalog=([^;]+)').Groups[1].Value
$newConnection = $newConnection.Replace($dbName+';', $newDbName+';')
```

**So the Regex is:**

For Data Source: `(?i)data source=([^;]+)`

For Initial Catalog: `(?i)initial catalog=([^;]+)`

For User name: `(?i)user id=([^;]+)`

For Password: `(?i)password=([^;]+)`

Comment: Thanks @Shayki. Can we replace the whole connectionstring with regex expression ? (="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-WebApplication45-20140804053515.mdf;Initial Catalog=aspnet-WebApplication45-20140804053515;Integrated Security=True"
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient")

Comment: The VSTS variable is the full connection string?

Comment: Try this regex: `connectionString=([^/>]*)`, put this regex on the `pattern` and in `repl` put the VSTS variable.

Comment: I would recommend this change instead so that you don't grab other settings as well:
**connectionString="([^"]*)**